# Problem: proxy_pass not working using upstream

Tags: nginx

Here is what works:

```
server {
    ...
    
    location ~ ^/(login|logout) {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://api.stage.site.com;
    }
}
```

Here is what does not work:

```
upstream backend {
    server api.stage.site.com:443;
}

server {
    ...
    
    location ~ ^/(login|logout) {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://backend;
    }
}
```

In the second case I get redirected to the another server from the same machine. I don't seem to get any logs. Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: By default, Nginx uses `proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;` which means the upstream server receives a request with the Host request header set to `api.stage.site.com` and `backend` respectively. Unfortunately, there's no way to use the value from the `upstream` block, which makes `upstream` less useful in these cases.

Comment: @RichardSmith What about this example? They state it's working. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/#complete-example